# What Does Intent.putExtra will do

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android and I use intents to transfer data from one Activity to another. I just wanted to know whether the object reference or object copy is sending to the second Activity.

Comment: copy of object is send with putExtra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intent.putExtra sends a copy of the object it is not the same reference when you get the extra from the intent you make the new reference there

Comment: Thanks JRowan is there is any chance for passing reference i mean i need to use same object whenever any change occurs in the object it need to be reflected in the Second Activity

Comment: if you make it static instead of passing it with putExtra you can reference it throughout your whole app in the same instance

Answer (score 1):

intent.putExtra is used to send information between the activity.
Here is an example

Use this to "put" the file

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String keyIdentifer  = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```
String newString
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```